# Restrict Auto case-number field to specific record type

Tags: case, formula-field, record-type

I've a custom auto case-number field for one of my case record type (Quality Report). Every time a new case is created, the auto case number is generated (ex: QR-1287). However, the auto number field is generated even when a case is created in other record types (QR-1288, QR-1289....) . How do I avoid it? I want the auto case number field to update only on a single case record type, the case number should QR-1288 only if the record-type is of Quality Report. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autonumber field in SF is the same auto number field you get in the Traditional Database (Oracle,MySQL etc) . That being said as its handled by the Internal Database and not the SF implementation there is no way one can change this behavior.

You can do a workaround,

1. Make the name field as Text instead of autonumber
2. Create a new Autonumber field you want
3. Create a workflow rule, on created that checks the record type and then updates the name of the record using the autonumber field present on the record.

Comment: Hey Pranay, Thanks for the reply. If I use the above WFR, Would I be able to fire the auto-number only for specific record type then?

Comment: Yes you can add condition in WF rule that will allow you to fire on when certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest code-based handling for the above problem,

In the before Insert section of trigger:
Use two variables:-
(a) recordTypeId and (b) count

Steps:-
String recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(*-YOUR Record Type Label- *).getRecordTypeId();

integer count = database.countQuery('SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId =: recordTypeId');

Now iterate on the new list:
for(Case caseObj : Trigger.New){
    if(caseObj.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId){
        count = count + 1;
        caseObj.*text field* = '*your prefix*- '+String.valueOf(count);
    }
}